# Getting absurd times for thread creation in Windows when using CreateThread()

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

So I have created following simple program to measure the average time to create a process or thread on my machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <time.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data) {

  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    STARTUPINFO si = {0};
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
    clock_t begin, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000000;i++){
        begin = clock();
        CreateProcess(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
        end = clock();
        cpu_time_used += ((double) (end - begin)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    }
    /* since we're running 1 000 000 (1 million) times we divide by 1 
     * million and since to get the time in ns instead of ns we multiply by
     * 1 billion we simply multiply by 1000 since 1 billion / 1 million = 1000.
     */
    printf("Average time to create a process = %f ns\n", cpu_time_used * 1000); 

    cpu_time_used = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000;i++){
        begin = clock();
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
        end = clock();
        cpu_time_used += ((double) (end - begin)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    }
    /* since we're running 1 000 000 (1 million) times we divide by 1 
     * million and since to get the time in ns instead of ns we multiply by
     * 1 billion we simply multiply by 1000 since 1 billion / 1 million = 1000.
     */
    printf("Average time to create a Thread = %f ns\n", cpu_time_used * 1000);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The Following results:

```
Average time to create a process = 89.000000 ns
Average time to create a Thread = 112055.000000 ns
```

The time for creating a process seems reasonable enough, but why would creating a thread be taking over a thousand times longer than creating an entirely new process?

Comment: Since you pass both a null `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` argument to [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), there's nothing to run and no need to create a process. So it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: You also have a flaw in your timing calculation... The `clock` function doesn't give you elapsed CPU time in Windows (using the VS CRT), it gives you the *wall clock* timing. So the time you count also includes the time the created threads ran and your main thread was sleeping.

Comment: clock() doesn't work the way you think it does.  Use QueryPerformanceCounter() instead.

Comment: "A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the _beginthreadex and _endthreadex functions for thread management" (source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread). It's unlikely that you do anything completely without the C runtime, so my choice is to be safe rather than sorry and use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there were several errors with my approach that I will explain here along with the complete final code at the end.

1. The CreateProcess() call was doing nothing instead of starting a program that does nothing.
   To fix this we chan `CreateProcess(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);` to `CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);` and for good measure we suspend the process.
2. Windows limits programs to 2048 threads. Meaning an additional bottleneck was occurring after the 2048th thread as the program waits until threads are closed to open a new one. To avoid this I reduced my loops to only 1000.
3. clock() is inaccurate for multithreaded programs, as pointed by @Some programmer dude, instead, we use QueryPerformanceCounter(). Keep in mind that depending on your IDE and other factors QueryPerformanceFrequency might incorrectly return 10 MHz(had this problem with NetBeans, so changed to Visual Studio), so test it out first.

The fixed final code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 

#include <time.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data) {

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };

    LARGE_INTEGER begin, end, cpu_time_used;
    LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;
    cpu_time_used.QuadPart = 0;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);


    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&begin);
        CreateProcess("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
        cpu_time_used.QuadPart += end.QuadPart - begin.QuadPart;
        TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
    }
    cpu_time_used.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    cpu_time_used.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

    printf("Average time to create a process = %lld us\n", cpu_time_used.QuadPart / 1000);

    cpu_time_used.QuadPart = 0;
    HANDLE hThread;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&begin);
        hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);
        cpu_time_used.QuadPart += end.QuadPart - begin.QuadPart;
    }
    cpu_time_used.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    cpu_time_used.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;

    printf("Average time to create a Thread = %lld us\n", cpu_time_used.QuadPart / 1000);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Returning:

```
Average time to create a process = 8289 us
Average time to create a Thread = 26 us
```

Comment: Those times seem to be roughly in accord with values I measured some years ago on CO/Vista.  I can add:  'Average time for an existing thread to become running when the semaphore upon which it was waiting is signaled, and there is a core available to run it, = 4 us.